# Angular 2 CLI, Can I test only certain SPEC, instead of all of them?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-cli

I'm using angular 2 CLI for my web project, and I wrote a lot of unit tests, as my code base grows larger, the tests become more and more heavier. I was wondering if it's possible to test only certain part of the `spec` files I specified ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually turn off tests or just run specific tests, with the following syntax.

If you prefix "describe" blocks with an f, only that will run:

```
fdescribe()
```

If you prefix "it" blocks with an f, only that will run:

```
fit()
```

You can also prefix with an 'x' to not run a block:
xit() and xdescribe()

See: [How to execute only one test spec with angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683673/how-to-execute-only-one-test-spec-with-angular-cli)

Answer (score 1):

There is `test.ts` file

```
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

If i want to test only pipes i can write:

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /pipe\.spec\.ts$/);
```