# Running ng test with different test entry point

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner, angular-cli

Is there anyway to run `ng test` with a different test entry-point to the one specified in `.angular-cli.json`?

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8579#issuecomment-346313383 provides a solution for increasing rebuild times by using lazy loaded chunks. But I fear that breaking up the tests into chunks might cause some tests to be missed.

Ideally i would have two files:
`test.ts`, `test.tmp.ts`
with `test.ts` containing:

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

while `test.tmp.ts` has:

```
const context = require.context('./app/some_module/', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

This way, while developing, I can run something like `ng test --entry-point=test.tmp.ts`. Ideally test.tmp.ts will be git.ignored.

At the moment, its possible to call `ng test --config=different_karma.conf.js` to specify a different `karma.conf.js`, and within `karma.conf.js` you can change the reference to `test.ts` within that. However, this doesn't successfully run the tests, unless I change the `apps.0.test` entry point in `angular-cli.json` to `test.tmp.ts`.

The error I get is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string at src/test.tmp.ts:3
```

One solution is to create another app within .angular-cli.json which is a copy of the first with a different entry point, and call `ng test -app` but then you have to maintain two different app configs.

I can change test.ts directly each time, but its possible that might get committed.

Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43669082/5464931 makes it seem like changing `angular-cli.json` was not neccessary, but I can't seem to get that to work.

Comment: Can you post your new test.tmp.ts content?

Comment: test.tmp.ts content is exactly the same as test.ts but with 
`const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);`
changed to
`const context = require.context('./app/some_module/', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);`

But copied here anyway: 
[link](https://gist.github.com/DulithaRanatunga/35abda00536d7ad6b22c6579e3f34fe2)

Comment: Perhaps you might take a look at the ng test --main option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Delete **node_modules** folder and run `npm install`