# Angular Unit Test - Run by module or folder

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular project with Karma setup for unit test. The test and coverage works fine for all spec files, but from day to day the app gets bigger and it bothers me to run all tests, even if I'm focusing in a new module, so I wanted to run only some tests that I want to check, for example, I have a pipes folder and all I want to do is to run only the spec files in this folder, **I know I can update the context in my test.ts file but I don't want to update and revert that file each time...**

I tried to create a new Karma config file and updated the `files` property to add only the files I want but it didn't work. I don't know maybe I'm doing it wrong. (*See below a portion of the code in this file*)

Is there any solution or trick to do this? something like a separate karma config (ex: `karma.config.pipes.ts`) file that alters the context ?

```
// Override dev config
config.set({
  files: [
    {pattern: '../app/pipes/*.spec.ts'}
  ]
});
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54168380/604156 ;) It uses webpack but you can adapat it for your needs.

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if it's relevant anymore but as of 8.1 you can use the `--include` option for example:

`"ng test --include=**/folder/*.spec.ts"`

Sources: https://angular.io/cli/test#options and https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/07/03/angular-cli-8.1/

Also make sure to update your: @angular-devkit/build-angular.

Answer (score 1):

u can have test.ts file which contains following code

```
import "zone.js/dist/zone-testing";
import { getTestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import {
   BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
   platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing";

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
// here u can specify the folder
const context = require.context("./pipes", true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

and configure this file in tsconfig.spec.ts

```
{
 "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
 "compilerOptions": {
 "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
 "baseUrl": "./",
 "module": "commonjs",
 "target": "es5",
 "types": [
   "jasmine",
   "node"
 ]
 },
 "files": [
  "test.ts"
 ],
"include": [
"**/*.spec.ts",
"**/*.d.ts",
"./polyfills.ts"
]
}
```

Comment: I was very clear in my question, I know that and I don't want to edit and revert each time my test.ts, I was searching for a different way, where I can test all spec files in a module or folder for example and I always can test the whole app without editing the test.ts file.

Answer (score -3):

Just add "f" in front of your need to run **describe**,
like this

```
fdescribe('My pipe Testing', () => {
   it('', ()=>{
   });
});
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question