# How to invoke angular component tests from protractor?

Tags: angular, protractor

I have a vanilla Angular7 project that was generated via `ng` CLI and in there I have a component that I would like to test: `src/app/mini-cal/mini-cal.component.spec.ts`

I don't know of any way to ask angular cli tool to do this for me, the following combinations **failed**:

```
ng test --specs='src/app/mini-cal/mini-cal.component.spec.ts'
ng test -- --specs='src/app/mini-cal/mini-cal.component.spec.ts'
```

So I decided to point `protractor` at it like so:

```
protractor e2e/protractor.conf.js --specs='src/app/mini-cal/mini-cal.component.spec.ts'
```

which worked in getting at the file of interest but its missing additional configuration for:

- zone

  ```
  - Failed: Zone is needed for the async() test helper
            but could not be found. Please make sure
            that your environment includes
            zone.js/dist/zone.js
  ```
- testbed initialization

  ```
  - Failed: Cannot read property 'injector' of null
  ```

Usually all of this is available in `src/test.ts` and used by `ng test` automatically ... but now that I'm starting the process via `protractor`, I need to incorporate it into my `e2e/protractor.conf.js` file's `onPrepare()` method somehow.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You trying to do a unit test or an e2e test? You're specifying one file which makes it seem like a unit test. The Angular CLI uses Jasmine (testing framework) and Karma (test runner) for the unit tests and Protractor for e2e tests: https://angular.io/guide/testing. What does your test file look like? IMHO Jest gives a much better test running experience (ability to run specific tests by pattern matching, run only on changed files in your git working copy, interactive watching mode, snapshots, etc).

Comment: Ah I think you've found the cracks in my understanding. I want to test components so I am doing unit testing not e2e and shouldn't try to use protractor for this! I suppose then instead of looking at protractor for specifying a specific file for testing ... I should look at an alternative such as Jest. Please feel free to add your comment as an answer so I may mark it as the correct solution.

Comment: I have a bunch of experience using Jasmine/Karma with AngularJS and Jest with React, but none testing in Angular 2+. No idea how the Angular CLI is for testing or how well Jest works with Angular. (I tried using Jest with AngularJS once and couldn't get the config completely working.) So don't hate me if things don't work as planned :)

Comment: If you want to try the Jest route, these links make it look pretty easy https://github.com/briebug/jest-schematic https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular https://www.xfive.co/blog/testing-angular-faster-jest/ https://blog.angularindepth.com/integrate-jest-into-an-angular-application-and-library-163b01d977ce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are testing a single component, I believe you are trying to write and run a unit test, not an e2e (end to end) test. Unit tests generally only test a small unit (like a component or service or function) and are purposely scoped to make sure that unit does what is expected without having to worry about how external units are implemented. An end to end test (I've never written one so correct me if I'm wrong) would fire up your whole app and interact with it to test if units are working together correctly (think testing whole pages, multiple 
 components interacting, navigating, etc).

The Angular CLI uses the Karma test runner to run the unit tests in a browser environment and Protractor for e2e tests (I don't know the specifics of how Protractor runs tests.) See [Angular's Testing Guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing). So `ng test` runs Karma and `ng e2e` runs Protractor. Both types of tests use Jasmine as the testing framework for actually writing the test code.

It appears others have struggled with running a single unit test. You can use Jasmine's focused test feature to display output from a single `it` or `describe` block by changing them to `fit` or `fdescribe`. But that doesn't stop the code in other test files from being compiled or loaded, just keeps other `describe` or `it` blocks from running. You can see [How to execute only one test spec with angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683673/how-to-execute-only-one-test-spec-with-angular-cli) for attempts at doing other things.

I've enjoyed using Jest for all my React tests and I believe Jest gives a much better test running experience (ability to run specific tests by pattern matching, run only on changed files in your git working copy, interactive watching mode, updating snapshots, etc). You can look at the [Jest cli options](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#running-from-the-command-line) to see how to run only specific tests. Jest is both a testing framework (which is very much a copy of Jasmine syntax) and a test runner. Jest can use [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) or node to run your tests and doesn't need to run a real browser. Looks like Karma might have some support for jsdom now too...

If you want to go the Jest route, using [Jest Angular Schematic](https://github.com/briebug/jest-schematic) seems like the easiest way to add Jest to an Angular project and has a corresponding [article](https://www.xfive.co/blog/testing-angular-faster-jest/) about it.

Comment: Thanks @scotty-waggoner ... this is all legit. Also since I was only trying to test some functions inside my component, not so much the component's UI behavior ... setting up Unit testing with TypeScript  and pointing that at the component file also worked for me: https://journal.artfuldev.com/unit-testing-node-applications-with-typescript-using-mocha-and-chai-384ef05f32b2