# ng test not running all the test cases

Tags: angular6

I suppose if I run `npm run test`, `Angular` will pick `test` script from `package.json` and will run all the tests in `src/app`. My `test` script is

```
 "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "ng test --source-map=false",
  },
```

But when I run `npm run test` in `cmd`, only one test is executed. Why?

```
C:\Users\RSI\Documents\manu data\Documents\manu\codingjedi\code_related\code\frontend\web\ui>npm run test

> ui@0.0.0 test C:\Users\RSI\Documents\manu data\Documents\manu\codingjedi\code_related\code\frontend\web\ui
> ng test --source-map=false

 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active(node:28448) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead                                                               10% building modules 3/4 modules 1 active …\frontend\web\ui\src sync /\.spec\.ts$/10 08 2019 07:25:27.938:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
10 08 2019 07:25:28.061:WARN [karma]: Port 9876 in use
10 08 2019 07:25:28.072:INFO [karma]: Karma v2.0.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9877/
10 08 2019 07:25:28.075:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
10 08 2019 07:25:28.098:INFO [launche10 08 2019 07:25:38.946:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9877/
10 08 2019 07:25:39.060:INFO [Chrome 76.0.3809 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket X1Z9Eyn75PTPX__XAAAA with id 84815404
Chrome 76.0.3809 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 174 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
LOG: 'dialog message request received ', DialogServiceContext{sender-id: 5, additional-info: QuestionDetailContext{messaLOG: 'dialog message request received ', DialogServiceContext{sender-id: 5, additional-info: QuestionDetailContext{message: 'message from dialog context', additionalInfo: QuestionDetailAdditionalInfo{}}}
Chrome 76.0.3809 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 174 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
LOG: 'dialog message request received ', DialogServiceContext{sender-id: 5, additional-info: QuestionDetailContext{message: 'message from dialog context', additionalInfo: QuestionDetailAdditionalInfo{}}}
LOG: 'dialog message emitted ', DialogServiceMessageContext{message-to-display: 'message from dialog context', return-coLOG: 'dialog message emitted ', DialogServiceMessageContext{message-to-display: 'message from dialog context', return-context: DialogServiceContext{sender-id: 5, additional-info: QuestionDetailContext{message: ..., additionalInfo: ...}}}
Chrome 76.0.3809 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 174 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
LOG: 'dialog message emitted ', DialogServiceMessageContext{message-to-display: 'message from dialog context', return-context: DialogServiceContext{sender-id: 5, additional-info: QuestionDetailContext{message: ..., additionalInfo: ...}}}
LOG: 'received message fromm dialog service', DialogServiceMessageContext{message-to-display: 'message from dialog context', return-context: DialogServiceContext{sender-id: 5, additional-info: QuestionDetailContext{message: ..., additionalILOG: 'received message fromm dialog service', DialogServiceMessageContext{message-to-display: 'message from dialog context', return-context: DialogServiceContext{sender-id: 5, additional-info: QuestionDetailContext{message: ..., additionalInfo: ...}}}
Chrome 76.0.3809 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 174 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
LOG: 'received message fromm dialog service', DialogServiceMessageContext{message-to-display: 'message from dialog context', return-context: DialogServiceContext{sender-id: 5, additional-info: QuestionDetailContext{message: ..., additionalIChrome 76.0.3809 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 174 (skipped 173) SUCCESS (0.193 secs / 0.048 secs)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute only one test spec with angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683673/how-to-execute-only-one-test-spec-with-angular-cli)

Comment: silly me! one of the test cases was marked `fit` so only it was getting executed